# Joomla Discover is asking for FTP Login Details

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.9

I am working `Joomla! 3.9` website and wanted to check that all extensions etc were installed correctly. I used the Joomla `Extensions > Manage > Discover` option. Nothing was found but above the message was a request for Login details saying

> "For installing or uninstalling Extensions, Joomla will most likely
>   need your FTP account details. Please enter them in the form fields
>   below".

Why? Has the site been hacked? I've never needed to use FTP details for installing extensions.

[image]

p.s. Can someone with a 50 reputation add the tag `Joomla-3.9`?

Comment: Is your hosting on IIS?  I believe it adds that message when you are on IIS instead of Apache.

Comment: Thanks for asking, but no, it's a Litespeed server which is supposed to be compatible with most Apache features.

Comment: Is FTP enabled in Global Configuration?

Comment: Doh! Yes, FTP was enabled. I normally turn it off. Just as well this was only a test site. Thank you, Sharky

Comment: @Sharky would you please post an answer so that credit can be awarded to you and this page can be marked resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Oops, I'd forgotten to disable FTP in Global Configuration. All sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **core Joomla message** of the core Joomla installer component: **com_installer**. I have not yet checked when and with which settings this message will appear, but you can find this message text in the ./administrator/languages/com_installer.ini file at line 114. So your site was not hacked. Installer can ask for FTP Login Details at particular settings. The **com_installer** (in your case particularly), **com_config**, and **com_joomlaupdate** can ask these credentials (also third party **akeeba** components).